# Касательно заголовка сайта

Tags: обсуждение, дефект, статус-завершено

Сверху про "...этимологов, и энтузиастов русского языка" - зачем запятая перед союзом "и"?

Comment: Приведите заголовок полностью. Иначе непонятно, нужна запятая или нет.

Comment: Запятая не нужна. Я передам сообщение об ошибке администраторам сайта.

Answer (score 1):

Добрый день! Спасибо за отзыв. Это ошибка, до которой почему-то не доходят руки. Обязательно поправим в ближайшее время.

Comment: Скажите, а почему Вы поставили тире в "почему-то"?

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой это, очевидно, опечатка: там должен быть дефис. Осмелюсь подправить :)

Comment: Ну хорошо, а я думал специально.) Интересно, как можно короткое тире случайно поставить. :)

Comment: Кстати, @Aer, а что там насчёт разделителей тысячных разрядов?

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой На сколько я знаю, существую технические сложности с реализацией разделителей в зависимости от языка, к сожалению. О дефекте знаем, он находится в базе!

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky тогда хорошо) Я только не пойму, почему раньше было на каждом языке по-своему, а теперь что-то изменилось (если я правильно помню). А ещё не подскажете, Николай, если я ставлю "@имя", а после него запятую или ещё какой знак, оно свою функцию перестаёт тогда выполнять, т. е. сообщение тому человеку не приходит при такой записи?

Comment: @Aer нормально получил [уведомление](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91ClA.jpg) с запятой. И, кажется, по ссылке сообщение удалено уже.

Comment: @alexolut да, уведомления, действительно, приходят. Я исправлю статью и добавлю верную информацию (для этого она и была удалена).